# Run EXE in another system without any Fortran support, extra DLLs support & Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ide, fortran, intel-fortran

Suppose I make a simple program to add two numbers. When I use command line to compile, create object (obj), link and create exe, using the commands:

```
ifort add.f90

ifort -o add add.obj
```

The exe created by this method will run in any other system (running Windows) irrespective of the support of Fortran, Visual Studio, extra DLLs in it.

### Now:

When I use the Visual Studio to compile, build and even release than the exe created by this method which I find in some

```
C:\Users\VIVEK\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Console1\Debug or 

C:\Users\VIVEK\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Console1\Release
```

directory cannot run on independently run on any system (like it did in command line case). The other system reports for some error regarding DLLs.

### Here I need help:

I want to create the 'independent' exe from Visual Studio just like the command line did. I searched a lot in different forums and throughout the web but didn't found the exact steps that could help me. I know some dll linking or something is missing, such as dependencies. I am just a beginner in Visual Studio and it's settings. Can someone help me with the detailed step-by-step procedure?

I've also noted the difference in the size of the two exe. Eg., the exe created by the command line will be roughly near 100-120 KB (which I believe is the reason for it's independent nature). However, the exe created using the Visual Studio is around 20-30 KB.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/657071

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio may default to dynamic linking to the Intel runtime libraries. I believe you can force VS to link your application statically (no DLLs needed) by giving `ifort` the `/libs:static` option in the compilation phase of the project. You may also need to use the `/threads` option as well.

Someone with a deeper understanding of `ifort` or the linking process on Windows might be able to explain why `/threads` is necessary; all I know is that build documentation for the last Fortran code I shipped for Windows used `/libs:static` and `/threads` despite the application being single-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is called runtime. you can search more on the internet with that topic. 
for example if you are on windows then this might help :
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/redistributable-libraries-of-the-intel-c-and-fortran-compiler-for-windows/
but if you work with VS version then you should check that out.

Answer (score 0):

In line with @arclight, refer to my topic [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/Difficulties-in-obtaining-exe-file-from-Fortran-code-in-Visual/td-p/1295448). Using static instead of dynamic libraries solved my problem, that is similar to yours.